# Confused about connecting slider mechanism to flanged ball nut

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, stepper-motor, linear-motion

This is probably a really basic questions but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to proceed.

I need very smooth and precise motion over a short distance ~2inches, but it needs to be fast since this will be a shutter. I am not sure what is feasible but I was planning on getting a high rpm stepper (5000rpm) to drive the ball screw.

Where I am stuck is the ball nut which spins with the screw... How do I get some sort of gantry plate or something on it to complete my sliding mechanism?

I am looking at mcmaster, and found [this](https://www.mcmaster.com/3405N142/). But I am not sure what else I need. In CNC videos they have the spinning nut that screws into a block but I am not sure what that is called.

Also for a larger sanity check is there a more appropriate approach of designing sliding mechanism with very short travel distances?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So shutter for what? A grain trailer to stop the grain coming out when there are several tonnes of grain in the hopper? Or a shutter on a camera lens?